# Difference between Flash, Air, and ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript, air

can someone describe these 3 technologies, the differences between the, and how they relate to each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this Armor Game's post](http://armorgames.com/community/thread/2731143/what-is-the-difference-flash-flex-and-air-oh-my):

> Flash - Vector-based animation package that, over time, has developed
>   scripting and gradually gotten more complex and supported more
>   interactive results to the point where it's used for things like
>   complicated Flash games and other such stuff.  Can be scripted with
>   ActionScript and compiles to the SWF format.  Flash is part of the CS
>   packages, which are in the high hundreds / low thousands.  There's
>   also different versions of the package available, so make sure the one
>   you get has what you need.
>
> AIR - An enhanced API and separate runtime for Flash applications
>   centered around desktop support.  A program written for AIR can do all
>   the fun things that the normal Flash player can't, such as catching
>   the middle and right clicks.  I'm fuzzy on the details, though.  Not
>   really relevant if you're just interested in making Flash games to go
>   up on the web, but it might be worth looking into if you want to have
>   a more fully-featured downloadable version of your game.

Actionscript (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) -

> a scripting language originally
>   developed by Macromedia Inc. (now
>   owned by Adobe Systems). It is a
>   dialect of ECMAScript (meaning it has
>   the same syntax and semantics of the
>   more widely known JavaScript), and is
>   used primarily for the development of
>   websites and software targeting the
>   Adobe Flash Player platform, used on
>   Web pages in the form of embedded SWF
>   files.

Comment: So when deciding to write an app, I have to choose between Flash and AIR, right? And ActionScript is the language used for both of them?

Comment: you should use blockquotes and hyperlinks to clarify that your answer is citing Wikipedia and other internet resources.

Comment: @whydna right, also look into using Flex if you are writing a data-driven app.

Answer (score 0):

There are two runtime Flash Platforms one is Flash Player and other Adobe AIR(Adobe Integrated Runtime). Adobe Flash Player is a highly expressive cross-platform runtime that works across all the browsers which have the Flay Player plugin. Flash Player delivers the SWF files that runs within the browser, while AIR delivers the .air standalone applications that run on desktop outside the browsers.
You can find more details about AIR & Flash from here: http://readymadeflash.com/blogs/what-is-the-difference-between-adobe-AIR-and-flash.html